# How to inject HTTP call using mono.cecil

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

I am trying to push HTTP call using mono cecil but getting issue while caling
Actual Code in C#:

```
var res = client.GetAsync(urlParameters);
```

Converted using https://cecilifier.me/

```
    var lv_res32 = new VariableDefinition(assembly.MainModule.ImportReference(typeof(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)));
    CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Body.Variables.Add(lv_res32);
    var Ldloc33 = il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, lv_client13);
    il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Append(Ldloc33);
    var Callvirt34 = il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, assembly.MainModule.ImportReference(TypeHelpers.ResolveMethod("System.Net.Http", "System.Net.Http.HttpClient", "GetAsync",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,"", "System.String")));
    var Ldloc35 = il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, lv_urlParameters10);
    il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Append(Ldloc35);
    il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Append(Callvirt34);
    var Stloc36 = il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, lv_res32);
    il_CodeInsight_WorkThreadFunction_.Append(Stloc36);
```

This code generate these IL

```
|       > IL_0000: ldloc V_2
|       > IL_0000: ldloc V_1
|       > IL_0000: callvirt System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> System.Net.Http.HttpClient::GetAsync(System.String)
|       > IL_0000: stloc V_3
```

And when I run the code I am getting below error:

```
Hello from OtherUnhandled exception. System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected 
an invalid program.
   at QualityInsight.CodeInsight.WorkThreadFunction()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Can anyone help here...

Comment: Can you share [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi @PawełŁukasik, thanks for your reply. I am able to inject the HTTP request.

Comment: If so then please share your solution so that future seekers can use it.

Comment: @AmitKumar I am also interested in the actual fix (I am the author of Cecilifier); I am almost sure it has to do with *async* (Cecilifier does not have any support for that). BTW, you can create a gist and use a url like: https://cecilifier.me?gistid=xxxx